# Recommended notebook for coding and music production

Tags: laptop, development, music

I'm searching for a notebook to code on and make music. I really like the Lenovo X1 carbon however it is a bit expensive without a Blackfriday sale ;) so maybe there is a similar one.

What I want:

- 13 - 15 Inch
- SSD
- lightweight

I'm a developer, so I should be able to build my Visual Studio solutions and run node server.

I'm also a music producer working with FL Studio software from Image-Line. FL Studio does require "full SSE2 support" [What are the system requirements of FL (and does it run on a Mac)?](https://support.image-line.com/knowledgebase/base.php?ans=82) as well as [What computer should I get for music creation?](http://support.image-line.com/knowledgebase/base.php?id=55&ans=214).

I have a desktop at home with a 24 inch screen, so I don't need a big screen.

Comment: "vs" does that mean Visual Studio? What kinds of solutions and how large? What is the node server for? Are you wanting to host a server or is it for development? What is "fl studio"?

Comment: yes vs is visual studio. My solutions are medium, i would say. The node server is just for dev. And fl studio  is fruity loops from image line, it's a daw (digital audio workstation).

Answer (score 1):

I bought an ultra-book *Asus UX410UQ-GV068T* for coding and graphism.

**Spec:**

- **CPU:** Intel Core i7 7500U 2.7Ghz
- **GPU:** Geforce GTX 400MX 2GB Vram
- **SCREEN:** 14" Led screen Full Hd
- **DATA:** SSD 128go + HDD 500go
- **RAM:** 8Go DDR4 2133mhz (+ i added 8go - 123€)
- **MORE:** 1x Usb3, 2x Usb2, Hdmi port

Beautiful design (silver), comfortable screen (it's a 13" case with a 14" screen with thin border) and beautiful color, backlit keyboard, battery 8 hours, large touchpad, ergonomic and pro.

Photoshop, Illustrator, Brackets and tons of tabs on chrome with music at the same time and the computer works like a charm. Linux compatible (useful with 2 Disks). CUDA 9. I even succeed to play Battlefield 1 on it (with good framerate on mid/low settings).

Personnaly, i searched for a long and didn't found the half for 1069€ (sales price).

---

If you want a notebook, something more powerful and not so expensive, you should look for [Gigabyte laptops](https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop) or [Msi laptops](https://www.msi.com/Laptops), there are both specialized in laptops for gaming.

Answer (score 0):

Top 4 Best Music Production and coding Laptops Reviews

1. Apple MacBook Pro – Best Mac for Music Production
   Price: $1899

[image]

```
> Wondering what laptop to tag along for your live concert recording,
> on-road show or studio time?
> 
> The MacBook Pro sports fitting hardware and software support for
> musicians and music producers regardless of skill level. It comes with
> Apple’s Garageband music production software for basic recording and
> production out of the box. But professionals will appreciate that
> almost every decent, more engaging suites are supported here.
> 
> If you are a Logic diehard, though, you have no option but to use an
> Apple computer since Logic does not support Windows OS. And if you are
> asking for the absolute best music production laptop around, then
> pricing may not be your concern.
> 
> If you can drop as much on a MacBook Pro, you can expect impressive
> speed (with a Quad-core 2.9 GHz, Intel i7 processor), snappy
> performance (16 GB of DDR3 RAM), and fast SSD (512 GB) for a sizable
> chunk of top-tier DAW suites, samples, and so on.
> 
> The 15-inch display pops videos and images thanks to the 2800 by 1800
> resolution Retina Display but could be unsatisfactory if you prefer
> larger rooms to work on. For that, you get two USB 3.0 ports to
> connect to other audio and video interfaces, Bluetooth 4.0 for
> wireless connection, and Thunderbolt ports (only usable with other
> Apple peripherals, unfortunately).
> 
> If you choose to record on the fly or are doing a live concert, the
> MacBook Pro is decidedly durable, lightweight at just 3 lbs, reliable
> with that 10-hour battery life, and the sharp display won’t shudder
> under bright lights, either.
```

**[SEE ON AMAZON](https://amzn.to/2viJMso)**

2. Eluktronics P650RP6 Premium
   Price: $1,249.95

[image]

```
> For less than you’d have to cough up for a MacBook Pro, you get this
> Made in America beast puffing a horde of multitasking goodies with up
> to 64 GB of DDR4 RAM. From Sonar to Ableton to Studio One and all the
> way down to Point Tools and Audacity, this thing will reap through
> your heavy-handed, resource-hogging, pro DAW programs with shocking
> ease and flow.
> 
> That’s crazy good. There are four variants to choose from but each
> hosts a 6th Gen Intel Quad core i7 CPU. Prices vary with RAM and
> Storage upgrades. The base entrant affords you 256 GB SSD storage and
> 16 GB of DDR4 RAM for around $1,100—a good bargain compared to the
> harshier price tag on the MacBook Pro.
> 
> The flagship version beefs up storage (and RAM up to 64 GB) to a
> primary 512 GB SSD and additional 1TB HDD storage.
> 
> With all that RAM and processing power, it also swanks a truckload of
> connectivity options if you are planning to plug several MIDI
> controllers, as well as both audio and video outputs. It beats every
> other laptop here—includes two USB 3.1 Type C, three USB 3.0, 1 HDMI
> (with HDCP), and two mini Display ports.
> 
> So, while it is a 15.6-inch (Full-HD) portable beast, it could easily
> and optimally serve as a workstation replacement, any day. It might
> seem overkill for a music recording computer, too.
```

**[SEE ON AMAZON](https://amzn.to/2M21XvL)**

3. Asus ROG Strix (GL753VD) -Best for Gaming and Music Production
   Price: $1,035

[image]

```
> Choose this workhorse of a gaming laptop to crank up
> professional-quality audio and video at half the price of the MacBook
> Pro.
> 
> It hosts similar CPU specs as the MacBook Pro, and even ousts the
> latter with snappier DDR4 RAM and 1TB HDD storage. That might seem
> slower than the SSD option winded into the Apple computer, but Asus’
> HDD is a 7200 RPM beast that’s great for producers who want more room
> to record and run DAW suites without a need for external
> reinforcements.
> 
> Still, you get 17.3 inches of Full-HD (60 fps) display estate that’s
> reinforced with 4GB (DDR5) NVIDIA GeForce GTX graphics processing
> power. Not better than the MacBook Pro but ultra-resourceful if you
> use graphics-hogging DAW.
> 
> It is also surprisingly lightweight for the size at 6.6 lbs and packs
> a –hour power plant around the bottom. So, if you get to work out much
> this could be an affordable yet uncompromising music production laptop
> dream of.
> 
> That weight might lead you to prefer it as a studio-time machine. And
> it aptly fits that role with its array of connectivity ports including
> two USB 3.0, one USB 2.0, one HDMI, one LAN, and a couple more ports.
> 
> This Asus is a top contender for best Windows music production laptop,
> if not the laptop to beat overall, especially if you think the MacBook
> Pro is overpriced.
> 
> Better yet, check out the bustling Lenovo Y700 if you prioritize an
> immersive sound experience with all the top-performing (and priced)
> hardware components.
```

[**SEE ON AMAZON**](https://amzn.to/2AEbXHj)

4. Acer Aspire V17 Nitro
   Price: $1,319.67

[image]

This Black Edition Aspire is a serious machine. Similar to the Asus ROG Strixx above, it sports roomy 17.3-inch Ultra-HD (3840 by 2160) display for all the true-cinematic format videos and special effects you conspire to throw at it. That’s the kind of 4K display the Dell XPS 9560-7001SLZ PUS boasts—although a touch-screen on the Dell.

Acer also shoved 512 GB of the faster SSD and additional 1TB of HDD storage into it. It will handle all that in tandem and fluidly as it ships with 16 GB of DDR4 Dual Channel RAM inbuilt (to run with the 6th-gen Intel Quad-core i7 CPU—you can actually turbo boost it to 3.5 GHz).

One other honorable mention must be the DustDefender system. The heavy-handedness of professional-grade DAW suites make it too hot for many laptops to breathe, so it good to have a system built into a laptop to cool it down and blow the dust off the working innards. That’s to like. If it makes any difference, you get Windows 10 (64-bit Home) out of the box. Expect a 7-hour battery life.

**[SEE ON AMAZON](https://amzn.to/2MgMwNg)**